# How to check it's between Sunday 5:30PM and Friday 5:30PM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

How do I check if the current time is between Sunday 5:30 PM and Friday 5:30 PM?

I can find the day and time ranges separately but I think the time has to be combined with the day.

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()
if 0 <= now.weekday() <= 4:
    print ("It's a weekday!")
    if time(17, 30) <= now.time() <= time(17, 30):
        print "and it's in range"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the following 3 conditions:

1. The day is not Saturday
2. Either the day is not Friday, or the time is before 17:30
3. Either the day is not Sunday, or the time is after 17:30

In code, this is equivalent to:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

now = datetime.now()

if (now.weekday != 5
    and (now.weekday != 4 or now.time() <= time(17, 30)) 
    and (now.weekday != 6 or now.time() >= time(17, 30))):
        print("In range!")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get the datetime of the most recent Sunday at 5:30pm, and then check if it's within exactly 5 days:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
last_sunday = next((now - i * datetime.timedelta(days=1)) for i in range(7) if (now - i * datetime.timedelta(days=1)).weekday() == 6)
last_sunday_at_530 = datetime.datetime(year=last_sunday.year, month=last_sunday.month, day=last_sunday.day, hour=17, minute=30)
if (now - last_sunday_at_530) < datetime.timedelta(days=5):
    print("now is between Sunday at 5:30pm and Friday at 5:30pm")
else:
    print("Now is after 5:30pm on Friday but before Sunday at 5:30pm
```

If you want to check the reverse (after Friday but before Sunday) then you can simply start at `last_friday` and count forwards by only two days.

Answer (score 2):

Which time of day is within the range depends on the day:

1. On Sunday, times after 5:30 PM are in.
2. From Monday to Thursday, the time does not matter.
3. On Friday, times before 5:30 are in.

This leads to the following code:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
d = now.weekday()
t = now.time()

if (
    d == 6 and t >= datetime.time(17, 30)     # Sunday
    or 0 <= d <= 3                            # Monday–Thursday
    or d == 4 and t <= datetime.time(17, 30)  # Friday
):
    print("In range")
```